# Python client socket won't connect to server from a different machine?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I'm working on a client server program where the beginning of my client code is:

```
s = socket.socket()
host = [my ip address]
port = 30000
s.connect((host, port))
```

and the beginning of my server code is:

```
s = socket.socket()
host = [my ip address]
port = 30000
s.bind((host, port))

c = None
addr = None

s.listen(5)
while True:
   c, addr = s.accept()
   print ('New connection from: ', addr)
   break
```

If I run the server program on my computer, and then run the client program on the same computer, the client successfully connects.  But if I run the server program on my computer, and then go and run the client code on a different computer, the client will never connect and eventually time out.  How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Are both computers connected to the same local network?

Comment: Yes.  But I tried it with them on different networks (though I don't actually know if the version of my wifi network with "-5g" at the end is actually different from the original network.  If they're not different, then no, I have not tried it on different networks.)  Network stuff is very obviously not my thing, so my bad if the problem is obvious.

Comment: You need to make sure they are on the same network (same wifi name, even though im pretty sure both versions with and without `-5g` count as same network). And the other thing you need is make sure that you are using host computers local IP address. Not the localhost (127.0.0.1) and not your public IP address. How to find out computers local IP depends on the OS you have so here you can find instructions: https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-local-ip-address

Comment: I am using the local ip address.  The same one that you find next to IPv4 address in ipconfig.  I attempt to run the client program and server program on different computers on the same network, but the client still fails to connect.  It times out.

Comment: Nevermind.  I got it working somehow.  At some point I had switched out `host = [my ip address]` in the server program for `host = socket.gethostname()`, and apparently that does not get the correct ip address or something, so I switched it back to explicitly declaring the ip address, and I found out that I used the ipv4 address of the wrong network adapter last time.  So it works now.

Comment: Glad to hear. Can you check if `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())` returns the correct IP? Because that would probably be better than explicitly declaring IP since the IP might change in the future.